# Mining pool 0.2 minimal payout

Tags: mining-pools

New miner here trying to mine Ethereum on my R9 290 tri-x with a reported hashing rate of 28 MH/s.

So yesterday I was mining solo with ethminer console before I realized that you'd need months and be very lucky to get a block and actually get paid with 1 ETH.

Today I tried to mine with awesome miner and joined alpereum pool like one of the guides suggested.

So their minimal payout is 0.2 ETH and current ETH price is 370$ while the built in calculator says i'll be making 6.3 $ per day.

**So does that mean i'll need to mine nonstop for about 11 days before I'll get my first 0.2 ETH into my wallet?**

As a new miner i'm just trying to see if this is even working and waiting 11 days for result is a bit gruesome.

I've found some mining pools with 0.05 minimal payout... maybe I should try those but that would still take 3 days of testing before I get anything into my wallet if this is how this thing actually works...

Also at the time of writting this my miner started reporting an error:
Socket was closed remotely (by pool)
ETH: Job timetout, disconnect, retry in 20 sec...

Any advice you can give me? Am I understanding how this works properly?

Comment: You can actually change it from 0.2 to a minimum of 0.05 by clicking on settings next to account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are correct it would take "however many days" before getting a payout.

Alpereum changed to 0.05 ETH payout minimum recently but they are having some technical issues (this is why they lowered it).

Comment: I've changed to dwarfpool just cause it was the fastest 0.05 pool that I could find and now I can actually see my worker on their webpage and see what my balance is on there and how much I earned in last 24 hours :) (that didn't work on alpereum for some reason). 1 more day before i'll get issued a payout and then i'll maybe do some more research and change to another pool. Any suggestions? :D tnx for reply